# Extract file size and the date when the file is created in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using `rsync --recursive` to find all the files and directories:

```
 command = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    command = command.communicate()[0]
```

I get my output as:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 4,096 2013/01/20 22:37:39 files
```

How can I extract the file size and when the file is created in Python/Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
command  = "drwxr-xr-x 4,096 2013/01/20 22:37:39 files".split()
filesize = command[1] 
date = command[2]
```